# How to name a worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have a file (F) that contains several workbooks, each workbook has the same format. I do a conditional sum on each of the workbook under column conditions. I want to put the output within another workbook that contains one worksheet per workbook looped (contained within F).

I cannot find the good strategy to change the worksheet name in function of the looped workbook' name.

`Set Output_tot_n = Workbooks("Final_Output").Sheet_name.Range("B7")`

I got

> Error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method"

The whole code:

```vb
Sub Proceed_Data()
    
    Dim FileSystemObj As Object
    Dim FolderObj As Object
    Dim fileobj As Object
    Dim Sheet_name As Worksheet
    Dim i, j, k  As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Set FileSystemObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set FolderObj = FileSystemObj.GetFolder("C:\...\")
    
    For Each fileobj In FolderObj.Files
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileobj.Path)
    
        Set Output_tot_n = Workbooks("Final_Output").Sheet_name.Range("B7")
    
        If wb.Name = "AAA_SEPT_2018" Then
            Sheet_name = Worksheets("AAA")
        End If
        If wb.Name = "BBB_SEPT_2018" Then
            Sheet_name = Worksheets("BBB")
        End If
        If wb.Name = "CCC_SEPT_2018" Then
            Sheet_name = Worksheets("CCC")
        End If
    
        ' conditional sum

        With wb.Sheets("REPORT")
            For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row
                If .Cells(i, "O").Value = "sept" Then
                    k = .Cells(i, "M").Value
                End If
                j = j + k
                k = 0
            Next i
        End With
        Output_tot_n = j
        j = 0
                            
        wb.Save
        wb.Close
         
    Next fileobj
End Sub
```

Comment: sheet_name is not a valid identifier it shold be shett("name") or sheets(1).

Comment: Your syntax is off, plus you haven't defined `Sheet_name` when you first use it. And you need to use Set when assigning object variables. `set Sheet_name =...`.

Answer (score 1):

`Workbooks` is a `collection` (part of the actual `Application`-object). A collection in VBA can be accessed either by *index number* (index starts at 1) or by *name*. The *name* of an open Workbook is the name including the extension, in your case probably either `Final_Output.xlsx` or  `Final_Output.xlsm`.

`Sheets` and `Worksheets` are collections within a `Workbook`, again accessed via index or name (the difference is that `Worksheets` contains "real" spreadsheets while `Sheets` may also contain other sheet types, eg charts).

So in your case, you want to access a `Range` of a specific sheet of a specific workbook. The workbook has a fixed name, while the sheet name is stored in a variable. You can write for example

```
dim sheetName as string, sheet as Worksheet, Output_tot_n as Range
sheetName = "AAA"  ' (put your logic here)
set sheet = Workbooks("Final_Output.xlsm").Worksheets(Sheet_name)
set Output_tot_n = sheet.Range("B7")
```

or put all together (depending on your needs)

```
set Output_tot_n = Workbooks("Final_Output.xlsm").Worksheets(Sheet_name).Range("B7")
```

Answer (score 0):

No it actually works. Thank you again for your answers.

the problem was just is important to put "AAA_SEPT_2018.xlsx"